# Spotfire: Using one selection as a range for another datatable

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I've searched quite a bit for this and can't find a good solution anywhere to what seems to me like a normal problem for this product.

I've got a data table (in memory) that is from a rollup table(call it 'Ranges').  Basically like so:

```
id |   name   |  f1 |  f2 | totals 
 0 | Channel1 | 450 | 680 |     51 
 1 | Channel2 | 890 | 990 |    220
```

...and so on

Which creates a bar chart with Name on the X and Totals on the Y.

I have another table that is an external link to a large (500M+ rows) table.  That table (call it 'Actuals') has a column ('Fc') that can fit inside the F1 and F2 values of Ranges.

I need a way for Spotfire Analyst (v7.x) to use the selection of the the bar chart for Ranges to trigger this select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Actuals WHERE Actuals.Fc between [Ranges].[F1] AND [Ranges].[F2]
```

But there aren't any relationships (Foreign keys) between the two data sources, one is in memory (Ranges) and the other is dynamic loaded.

TLDR: How do I use the selected rows from one visualization as a filter expression for another visualization's data?

Answer (score 0):

My choice for the workaround:
Add a button which says 'Load Selected Data'

This will run the following code, which will store the values of F1 and F2 in a Document Property, which you can then use to filter your Dynamically Loaded table and trigger a refresh (either with the refresh code or by setting it to load automatically).

```
rowIndexSet=Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.GetSelection(Document.Data.Tables["IL_Ranges"]).AsIndexSet()

if rowIndexSet.IsEmpty != True:
    Document.Properties["udF1"] = Document.Data.Tables["IL_Ranges"].Columns["F1"].RowValues.GetFormattedValue(rowIndexSet.First)
    Document.Properties["udF2"] = Document.Data.Tables["IL_Ranges"].Columns["F2"].RowValues.GetFormattedValue(rowIndexSet.First)

if Document.Data.Tables.Contains("IL_Actuals")==True:
    myTable=Document.Data.Tables["IL_Actuals"]     
if myTable.IsRefreshable and myTable.NeedsRefresh:
    myTable.Refresh()
```

This is currently operating on the assumption that you will not allow your user to view multiple ranges at a time, and simply shows the first one selected.

If you DO want to allow them to view multiple ranges, you can run a cursor through your IL_Ranges table to either get the Min and Max for each value, and limit the Actuals between the min and max, or you can create a string that will essentially say 'Fc between  450 and 680 or Fc between 890 and 990', pass that through to a stored procedure as a string, which will execute the quasi-dynamic statement, and grab the resulting dataset.

Comment: Chelsea, Thanks!  that works, but is there a way to make the update automatic?  If the user clicks on a histogram bar (row count of everything between f1 and f2), that click action needs to be the same as your button script above.  Basically the selection of something in a chart forces a script to run.

Comment: I've never done this personally, but I imagine you could mimic this:
[link](http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2015/10/update-doc-property-trigger-ironpython.html)

Comment: wow.  that seems really elaborate.  Does Spotfire really not have a way for a selection to interact with a script directly?  Anyway, I've gotten really far with your original post as it is.  I think the client will just have to click on the damn refresh button for now :)  Thanks again